# Show that the equation $2a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4=c^2$ hasn't an integer solution

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

> Prove that: if $a,b,c\in Z$,and $a\neq 0$ show that: the equation
>   $$2a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4=c^2$$ has no solution.

My idea:
since
$$a^4+(a^2+b^2)^2=c^2$$

and I want use [Pythagorean triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)

and let  $$a^2=m^2-n^2. a^2+b^2=2mn, c=m^2+n^2,(m,n)=1$$
$$\Longrightarrow  m^2-n^2+b^2=2mn$$
$$\Longrightarrow (m-n)^2+b^2=2n^2$$

maybe my idea is wrong?

maybe the David H idea  is usefull?

since
$$2a^2(a^2+b^2)=(c-b^2)(c+b^2)$$

then $b$ and $c$ are either both even or both odd,and $c>b^2>b$
can usefull

But I can't continue.

Comment: Your equation can be rewritten as $2a^2(a^2+b^2)=(c-b^2)(c+b^2)$. This tells a few things: 1) $b$ and $c$ are either both even or both odd; and 2) $c>b^2>b$.

Comment: Also, to follow up on David H, it shows that $c \pm b^2$ are both the sum of two squares.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan,How  prove $c+b^2$ are both the sum of two squares?

Comment: @math110 Using the Pythagorean triple parametrization, $b^2=2mn-m^2+n^2$. Then, $c-b^2=2m^2-2mn$ and $c+b^2=2n^2+2mn$. I haven't quite figured out how to show that $c\pm b^2$ are both the sum of two squares from those lemmas, but I have a feeling it's on the right track.

Comment: @DavidH,Hello,I agree with you

Comment: @math110 Aha. $c-b^2=2m^2-2mn=(m-n)^2+m^2-n^2=(m-n)^2+a^2$. I also found $c+b^2=(m+n)^2-a^2$, which is a difference of squares, but still not sure how to write it as a sum of squares...

Comment: If $gcd(b,c)=d>1$ then $d \mid a$, and similarly for the other two pairings. Hence we may assume $a,b,c$ are pairwise relatively prime. So $\gcd(c-b^2,c+b^2)=1$ or $2$. Now Fermat's theorem on primes/factors of the form $u^2+v^2$ applies.

Comment: where does this question come from?

Comment: @PeterPatzt,my frend ask me,maybe is old  Math contest problem

Answer (score 3):

Let $(a,b,c)$ be a solution of
$$ 2a^4 + 2a^2b^2 + b^4 = c^2.$$
By evaluating the different values of $a,b,c$ modulo $4$ (**Edit:** $8$), one can easily show that $a$ must be even. If $b$ would also be even, then $(\frac a2, \frac b2, \frac c4)$ is also a solution to the equation. Hence if $a\neq 0$ we may assume that $b$ is odd and thus $c$.

Now we use, what you already wrote about Pythagorean triples. Note that automatically
$$ a^2 = 2mn\quad\text{and}\quad a^2 + b^2 = m^2-n^2$$
because $a$ is even. We also deduce the equations
$$ 2mn +b^2 = m^2 - n^2 \iff (m+n)^2 + b^2 = 2m^2.$$
So $m$ odd because $b$ is odd. The equation is also equivialent to
$$\left(\frac{m+n-b}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{m+n+b}2\right)^2 = m^2.$$
Therefore there must be $x$ and $y$ with
$$ m= x^2+y^2,\quad n= 2y(x-y),\quad b= y^2-x^2+2xy.$$
Therefore
$$2mn = 4(x^2+y^2)y(x-y)$$
must be the square $a^2$. It should be easy to check that the three factors are pairwise coprime, thus
$$ x^2+y^2 = z^2,\quad y = w^2, \quad x-y = t^2.$$
Putting these equations together we get
$$ z^2 = (t^2 + w^2) + w^4 = 2w^4 + 2w^2t^2 + t^4.$$
Hence $(w,t,z)$ is also a solution of the above equation, but $|w|<|a|$. By infinite decent, there is no solution $(a,b,c)$ with $a\neq 0$.

(Note that one needs to pay more attention on coprimeness at a few steps which I hope is correct or can be worked around.)

Comment: (1,1,1) is a solution modulo 4, so I do not see why $a$ must be even.

Comment: also I want ask it. @GeorgeShakan

Comment: $a$ must be even because of considerations $\pmod{8}$ (Considering $\pmod{4}$ is insufficient). Note if $a, b$ odd, then $a^2+b^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$, so $c^2 \equiv a^4+(a^2+b^2)^2 \equiv 1+4 \pmod{8}$, a contradiction. If on the other hand $a$ odd and $b$ even, then $c^2 \equiv a^4+(a^2+b^2)^2 \equiv 1+1 \pmod{8}$, a contradiction.

Comment: @IvanLoh,Oh,Nice explain!+1

Comment: Also note that the formula written for Pythagorean triplets is in fact for **primitive** Pythagorean triplets, so one really needs to first assume without loss of generality that $\gcd(a, b)=1$, before using the formula for primitive Pythagorean triplets.

Comment: @IvanLoh,hello,I don't know you meaning?

Comment: @IvanLoh that one can easily assume for the infinite descent argument. I havent worked out the details, that the second Pythagorean triples are in fact primitive. I hope it follows from the first triple being so.

Comment: @PeterPatzt That they are. If $p \mid \frac{m+n+b}{2}, \frac{m+n-b}{2}, m$ then $p \mid m+n=\frac{m+n+b}{2}+\frac{m+n-b}{2}, b=\frac{m+n+b}{2}-\frac{m+n-b}{2}, m$ so $p \mid m, n, b$, so $p \mid a, b$.

Comment: @math110 the formula you have only covers primitive solutions, and doesn't cover solutions such as $9^2+12^2=15^2$. But that is fine, as one can always WLOG assume $\gcd=1$.

Comment: @math110 It'd be nice to be accepted, if the solution helped ;)